# ¿Cómo puedo consumir una librería .dll en Android Studio?

Tags: c#, android, android-studio

Necesito consumir una librería para Android nativo, esta librería solamente se encuentra en formato **.DLL**.

Me gustaría saber cómo consumirla o en su defecto, saber como CONVERTIRLA a **.JAR**.

Después de bastante investigación solo encontré como realizar la conversión inversa de **.JAR** a **.DLL**.

Agradecería mucho su ayuda.
Saludos.

Comment: Me parece que son formatos totalmente distintos una librería .dll no se si es java-compatible, podrías probar javonet https://www.javonet.com

Comment: ¿Con que código se creo el .dll?

Answer (score 0):

Una DLL fue compilada totalmente a código máquina, en cambio un jar está compilado a nivel de **JVM** (bytecode).

Dudo mucho que exista una herramienta que convierta de **.DLL** a **.JAR**. Sin embargo, quizá te podría servir **JNI** (*Java Native Interface*).

En este post [Llamando dll C ++ desde Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9485896/calling-c-dll-from-java)
 hay un ejemplo de cómo usar esta característica.

Comment: Una dll no tiene porqué estár compilada a código máquina. En .Net las dll están compiladas a IL (similar a lo que hace java).